# How to get Rust autovectorization to generate VMULPS intead of VMULSS?

Tags: rust, optimization

I have a [function](https://godbolt.org/z/x56EYPrs1) to multiply two 16x16 matrices together, sized MxK and KxN. Textbook matrix multiplication. Compiling with `--release -C target-cpu=native` on CPU supporting AVX512.

One of the axes has been unrolled. It would seem that autovectorization should easily see a the multiplication of floats contiguous in memory, pack it into the `ymm`/`zmm` registers and do packed multiplication with `vmulps`, but instead it generates `vmulss`. As a result, it a significant slower.

The relevant code snippet:

```rust
        for h in 0..16 {
            let aval = a[(v * n) + h];
            let bvals = &b[(h * n)..(h * n + 16)];
            g0 += aval * bvals[0];
            g1 += aval * bvals[1];
            g2 += aval * bvals[2];
            g3 += aval * bvals[3];
            g4 += aval * bvals[4];
            g5 += aval * bvals[5];
            g6 += aval * bvals[6];
            g7 += aval * bvals[7];
            g8 += aval * bvals[8];
            g9 += aval * bvals[9];
            g10 += aval * bvals[10];
            g11 += aval * bvals[11];
            g12 += aval * bvals[12];
            g13 += aval * bvals[13];
            g14 += aval * bvals[14];
            g15 += aval * bvals[15];
        }
```

While I understand that it is a bit of *hit and miss* whether the optimizer would pick up on an opportunity to generate better code, I'm confused why the optimizer would not do what is expected above.

Interestingly, the below alternative, seemingly unoptimized code, causes the optimizer to generate 4x faster code, using `vmulps`, `vaddps`, etc. What does the optimizer see in this code that it doesn't see in the above code???

```rust
pub fn matmul(a: &[f32], b: &[f32], r: &mut [f32], m: usize, k: usize, n: usize) {
    let a = &a[0..(m * k)];
    let b = &b[0..(k * n)];
    for t in 0..k {
        for y in 0..m {
            for x in 0..n {
                r[(y * n) + x] += a[(y * n) + t] * b[(t * n) + x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a part of an effort to generate my own fast matrix multply function without resorting to unsafe, or explicitly using intrinsics. Unfortunately, the above makes me feel like it is hard to reason about step-by-step optimization with rustc and that this would be a fruitless effort.

Comment: Just to be sure: What version of Rust are you using, built on what version of LLVM? [AFAICT, you need to be using Rust 1.54 or higher, built on LLVM 12 or higher, to get proper noalias markings for mutable references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57259339/364696) which could be interfering with vectorization in *some* circumstances. That said, the snippet assigning to various `g#` variables doesn't seem like that should have any problems (it's not assigning back to a mutable reference); if it was going to be a problem, the `matmul` without manual loop unrolling might see the issue. *shrug*

Comment: As a side-note: Compilers are pretty smart. Manual loop unrolling doesn't always help, especially if it's hiding information from the compiler in some way.

Comment: @ShadowRanger rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21). How do I tell what version of LLVM rustc is using?

Comment: `rustc --version --verbose` should report it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I did the loop unrolling because I saw some siginificant performance differences previously. I've actually found rustc/llvm to be pretty dumb. It doesn't seem like I should need to accumulate to temp variables and then add to the result, but that makes for a 2x improvement.

Comment: @ShadowRanger rustc 1.75.0 (82e1608df 2023-12-21)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 82e1608dfa6e0b5569232559e3d385fea5a93112
commit-date: 2023-12-21
host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
release: 1.75.0
LLVM version: 17.0.6

Comment: FYI, looks like if you replace `-O` (equivalent to `-C opt-level=2`) with `-C opt-level=3`, it generates `vmulps` & `vaddps`. Typically, opt level 3 is what enables optimizations that bloat binary size (admittedly, it's usually stuff like automatic loop unrolling that gets enabled, and you did that yourself, manually). It's also making a larger binary; it's possible `-O` was being a little conservative to avoid bloating the binary.

Comment: @ShadowRanger seems hit and miss. On godbolt, it does get `vmulps`, but not on my local machine. Interestingly, the second code snippet might be a special case the compiler recognizes. If I manually unroll the `x` loop, it gets 4x _slower_ because it loses the `vmulps` instructions.

Comment: Note FP additions which are *not associative*. You may need to tell the compiler that FP math is associative. Often `-ffast-math` is enough to fix that for C/C++ compilers. I guess there is a similar flag in the Rust compiler. At least in LLVM there is a `-enable-unsafe-fp-math` flag. The second code performs a reduction only on the last loop with an array so the compiler can optimize that better (variables are not guaranteed to be contiguous and ordered the same way I think).

Comment: AFAIK different optimizer are used for the two codes. The former use the SLP vectorizer while the later use the basic loop vectorizer. SLP vectorisation is AFAIK more fragile (based on my experience so far) and more complex.